# Postgres SQL to search first occurred string

Tags: postgresql

I have this table **Basket** with a **TEXT** type column, This Notes field is free from text field, just for simplicity, I used one space between words in the example below, it can have commas or colons or any punctuation marks.
I am searching for the first fruit found in the Notes field for a given list of three fruits: **Apple, Orange, Banana** - This search criteria list is fixed.

| Notes |
| --- |
| Banana; Apple, Bread. Oats! Milk |
| Orange, Apple;,. Banana: |
| Bread'' 'Oat &Milk |
| Apple, ;Sugar :Banana ,Orange. |

Query

```
SELECT Notes, CASE WHEN Notes ~* 'Apple' Then 'Apple'
                    WHEN Notes ~* 'Banana' Then 'Banana'
                    WHEN Notes ~* 'Orange' Then 'Orange'
              ELSE NULL 
            END AS First_Fruit_Found
FROM Basket;
```

**My Query Results:**

| Notes | First_Fruit_Found |
| --- | --- |
| Apple Sugar Banana Orange | Apple |
| Orange Apple Banana | Apple |
| Bread Oat Milk | NULL |
| Banana Apple Bread Oats Milk | Apple |

**Expected Results:**

| Notes | First_Fruit_Found |
| --- | --- |
| **Apple** Sugar Banana Orange | Apple |
| **Orange** Apple Banana | Orange |
| Bread Oat Milk | NULL or Blank |
| **Banana** Apple Bread Oats Milk | Banana |

My Query with CASE statement gives results with the fruit that is found in the CASE statement order, I want to have the results with the First Fruit that I found in the Notes column, Please help if we can rewrite this query using re or any STRING functions/Operators in Postgres

Comment: Does 'xyzAppleabc' match as 'Apple' or not?

Comment: Yes, it should return Apple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regexp_match()` for that.

```
select notes, 
       (regexp_match(notes, '(?i)(apple|banana|orange)'))[1] as first_fruit
from basket;
```

`regexp_match()` returns an array of all matches in the order they are found. `[1]` then picks the first array element. I used a case-insensitive match by specifying `(?i)`. If you don't want that, remove the `(?i)` and specify the search words in the case you want them found.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=07df53c2628a826e5c1041010107307d)

Comment: This works perfectly for my case, I have to learn  more on Regular Expressions, they are quite powerful in string search.